# Resizing a box width from left to right using pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a box move and resize.

I have perfected the moving part and the resizing for the right and bottom.

I am having an issue resizing left and top.

Here are my initial vars ...

```
var mousePosition;
var offset;
var wrSizeOffset, wlSizeOffset, hbSizeOffset;
var div;
var isDown = false;
var wlSizeDown, wrSizeDown, htSizeDown, hbSizeDown = false;
var divWidth, divHeight;
```

After that I check whether the box is on mouse down ...

```
div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

   isDown = true;

   offset = {
      x: div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      y: div.offsetTop - e.clientY
   }

   // get width without px
   divWidth = parseInt(div.style.width, 10);

});
```

And then I check mouse on move like so ...

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

mousePosition = {
  x: e.clientX,
  y: e.clientY
}

// move div while mouse is down
if(isDown){
  div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset.x) + 'px';
  div.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset.y) + 'px';
}

// resize the div from left to right
// I am having no issues here
if(wrSizeDown){
  div.style.width = divWidth + mousePosition.x - wrSizeOffset.x + 'px';
}

// resizing the div from right to left
// here is where I am having an issue ...
if(wlSizeDown){
  div.style.width = divWidth - (mousePosition.x - wlSizeOffset.x) + 'px';
  // specially the below line of code
  div.style.left = divWidth + (mousePosition.x - wlSizeOffset.x) + 'px';
}

});
```

Whenever I resize from right to left the div jumps around like it's adding to the style.left

How can I make this work?

Here is an example ...

```js
var mousePosition;
var offset;
var wrSizeOffset, wlSizeOffset, hbSizeOffset;
var div;
var isDown = false;
var wlSizeDown, wrSizeDown, htSizeDown, hbSizeDown = false;
var divWidth, divHeight;

div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.position = 'relative';
div.style.left = '100px';
div.style.top = '100px';
div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
div.style.border = '1px solid black';

wrSize = document.createElement('div');
wrSize.style.position = 'absolute';
wrSize.style.right = '-10px';
wrSize.style.top = '40px';
wrSize.style.width = '20px';
wrSize.style.height = '20px';
wrSize.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
wrSize.style.border = '1px solid black';

wlSize = document.createElement('div');
wlSize.style.position = 'absolute';
wlSize.style.left = '-10px';
wlSize.style.top = '40px';
wlSize.style.width = '20px';
wlSize.style.height = '20px';
wlSize.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
wlSize.style.border = '1px solid black';

htSize = document.createElement('div');
htSize.style.position = 'absolute';
htSize.style.left = '40px';
htSize.style.top = '-10px';
htSize.style.width = '20px';
htSize.style.height = '20px';
htSize.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
htSize.style.border = '1px solid black';

hbSize = document.createElement('div');
hbSize.style.position = 'absolute';
hbSize.style.left = '40px';
hbSize.style.bottom = '-10px';
hbSize.style.width = '20px';
hbSize.style.height = '20px';
hbSize.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
hbSize.style.border = '1px solid black';

document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(wrSize);
div.appendChild(wlSize);
div.appendChild(htSize);
div.appendChild(hbSize);

div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  isDown = true;

  offset = {
    x: div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
    y: div.offsetTop - e.clientY
  }

});

wrSize.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  wrSizeDown = true;

  wrSizeOffset = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  divWidth = parseInt(div.style.width, 10);

});

wlSize.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  wlSizeDown = true;

  wlSizeOffset = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  divWidth = parseInt(div.style.width, 10);

  console.log(divWidth);
  console.log(wlSizeOffset.x);

});

hbSize.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  hbSizeDown = true;

  hbSizeOffset = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  divHeight = parseInt(div.style.height, 10);

});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){

  isDown = false;
  wrSizeDown = false;
  wlSizeDown = false;
  hbSizeDown = false;

});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

  mousePosition = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  if(isDown && (!wrSizeDown && !wlSizeDown && !hbSizeDown)){
    div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset.x) + 'px';
    div.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset.y) + 'px';
  }

  if(wrSizeDown){
    div.style.width = divWidth + mousePosition.x - wrSizeOffset.x + 'px';
  }

  if(hbSizeDown){
    div.style.height = divHeight + mousePosition.y - hbSizeOffset.y + 'px';
  }

  if(wlSizeDown){
    div.style.width = divWidth - wlSizeOffset.x + mousePosition.x + 'px';
    div.style.left = divWidth + wlSizeOffset.x - mousePosition.x + 'px';
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d80000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here using [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead of CodePen.

Comment: @Barmar I will next time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Here is the code ...

```js
var mousePosition;
var offset;
var isDown = false;
var isResize = false;
var div, resize;
var divWidth, divHeight;
var originalWidth, originalHeight; // added this too

div = document.createElement('div');
resize = document.createElement('div');

div.setAttribute('id', 'div');
resize.setAttribute('id', 'resize');

document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(resize);

div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  isDown = true;

  offset = {
    x: div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
    y: div.offsetTop - e.clientY
  }

});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){

  isDown = false;
  isResize = false;

});

resize.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){

  isResize = true;

  resizeOffset = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  divWidth = div.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  originalWidth = div.getBoundingClientRect().left; // here is where i missed up

});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

  mousePosition = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  if(isDown && !isResize){
    div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset.x) + 'px';
    div.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset.y) + 'px';
  }

  if(isResize){
    div.style.width = divWidth - mousePosition.x + resizeOffset.x + 'px';
    div.style.left = originalWidth + mousePosition.x - resizeOffset.x + 'px'; // added originalWidth instead of divWidth
  }

});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ce4257;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#resize{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Please read the comments to understand what I have done.

If you are facing problems understanding the solution please comment and I will help.

Thank you,
Farris

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an eventlistener for the top at all. But when you're holding down `wlSizeDown`, you need to calculate left like so:

`div.style.left = divWidth - (wlSizeOffset.x - mousePosition.x) + 'px';`

and for `htSizeDown` event listener is created:

```
div.style.height = divHeight - mousePosition.y + htSizeOffset.y + 'px';
div.style.top = divHeight + mousePosition.y - htSizeOffset.y + 'px';
```

Comment: It works on first mouse move but when I release and try again it jumps around on the x axis. I have attached the snippet.